# Angular 2 observable chaining 2 event in succession and returning a final result

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs

i have the following code gets the current login user

```
 this._settingsUsersService.getCurrentLoginUser().subscribe(res=>{
     this.user = res;
 })
```

and  another code which takes the result of the first function and perform an operation which return a boolean true/false

```
this._coreSecurityService.isAuthorized(user);
```

how can i combine both operation together? something like

```
 canActivate():Observable<boolean> {

     this._settingsUsersService.getCurrentLoginUser().subscribe(res=>{
        this.user = res;
     })

    return this._coreSecurityService.isAuthorized(this.user);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the result, adding in your user auth function, for example:

```
 this._settingsUsersService.getCurrentLoginUser()
            .map(result => coreSecurityService.isAuthorized(result))
            .subscribe(res => 
               // do something
            )
```

Does this answer your question?